# Get complete stack trace from error for asp.net core app hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I got recently a .net core app from someone else and when I try host this app in my local IIS I see a error message with no much information.

[image: Error from my app]

What I want to do is get the correct error message but when I change the keys"stdoutLogEnabled" and "stdoutLogFile" in the web.config (generated after publish the site from VS2017), nothing haapens.
What can i do to see more details about the error?

I tried to do others things force to my web project run on a specific runtime and install the specific bundle in IIS.. for example
2.0.7

and install this bundle:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.0.7-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

but still I have the error.. i think a better idea instead to install all bundle what I can get should be get the details stack trace of the error....
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you check the Windows event log?

Comment: if you mean to event-viewer, then yes. EventViewer-Custom Views- Server Roles- WebServer..and any error there.. the same for the path: Windows Logs- Application. everthing is okay... @Amy some smart way to get the stack trace?